# National visa expiring before applying for EU Blue Card

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, schengen, blue-card

I am working in Germany for 4 months with national visa and currently in process of applying for an EU Blue card. Unfortunately I got an appointment only in December 1st week of 2018 and my national visa expires on last week of November, 2018. The Ausländeramt said there are not earlier available appointments. I was wondering the consequences of this as there would be around 15 days where I would be without a valid visa.

P.S. I visited the local Ausländeramt 4 times, and every time I was asked to email for an appointment, and every time I emailed them, I got no reply and I got an appointment on my 4th email to them. They have been extremely busy but I am quite uncomfortable with the fact that I will be without a valid stay/travel document in Germany for 15 days.

Comment: What nationality are you?  I suspect you should not work after your visa expires.  Can you get your visa extended (you do still have a month)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am from India. I did not know it was possible to extend the national visa.

Comment: I don't know that it *is* possible - but it's a sensible thing to ask.

Comment: Have you already submitted the application for the blue card?  It's common for a pending application for a residence permit to allow you to stay past the end of a visa's validity.  If you've already submitted the application, the fact that you haven't yet had the interview shouldn't matter.

Comment: No. I got the appointment to submit on 5th of December , 2 weeks past visa expiration date

Comment: Can you post your experience as an answer rather than as an update to the question?  Then please accept it.  Those who care more about site statistics than I do will thank you!  I suppose I will, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE- I talked to HR representative from my company and they helped me get an appointment at the Immigration office for Fiktionsbescheinigung, which is basically a temporary work permit. So anyone with the same situation I was in, please do talk to Ausländeramt regarding Fiktionsbecheinigung or also extending the type D visa, which I think can be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After the application for renewal has been made **before** the present permit has expired, the the permit is considered renewed until a final decision has been made:

> [**Was muss ich beachten, wenn meine Aufenthaltserlaubnis abläuft?**](https://www.bmi.bund.de/SharedDocs/faqs/DE/themen/migration/aufenthaltsrecht/aufenthaltsrecht-liste.html)
> Sie müssen dringend darauf achten, vor Ablauf der Geltungsdauer einen Antrag auf Verlängerung bzw. Erteilung eines anderen Aufenthaltstitels (beispielsweise einer Niederlassungserlaubnis) zu stellen. **Wird der Antrag rechtzeitig, d.h. vor Ablauf der Befristung gestellt, gilt der weitere Aufenthalt bis zur Entscheidung der Ausländerbehörde mit allen sich daran anschließenden Wirkungen (z.B. der Berechtigung zur Ausübung einer Erwerbstätigkeit) als erlaubt.** Eine verspätete Antragstellung (nach Ende der im Aufenthaltstitel genannten Befristung) kann erhebliche Rechtsnachteile zur Folge haben. Ihr weiterer Aufenthalt wäre dann unerlaubt. Sie sind dann ausreisepflichtig und dürften keiner Beschäftigung mehr nachgehen.

---

The problem here is whether making the **appointment** is to be considered sufficient.

In Berlin it is sufficient if

- the **residence permit** is valid on the day of the booking of the appointment
- and you show up to the booked appointment

The **residence and any work permits** will remain valid until the day of the appointment.

> [Mein Aufenthaltstitel wird vor dem Termin ungültig – Ist das ein Problem?](https://www.berlin.de/labo/willkommen-in-berlin/termine/)
> Ihr Aufenthaltstitel war an dem Tag der Buchung des Termins noch gültig?
> Dann wird der Aufenthaltstitel im Bundesgebiet bis zum gebuchten Termin als **fortbestehend betrachtet**.
> Dies gilt auch für die Nebenbestimmungen zu Ihrem Aufenthaltstitel. Das bedeutet, Sie können bis zum Termin weiter arbeiten oder studieren.
>
> Wichtig: Voraussetzung ist, **dass Sie zum gebuchten Termin kommen**.
>
> Reisen ins Ausland sind jedoch nur innerhalb der Gültigkeit des Ihnen zuletzt erteilten Aufenthaltstitels möglich.

Check the site of your local authority (probely where appointments are made) for a similar statement.

---

Making a pdf copy of the appointment would be a good idea

- printing a copy for your employer even better

---

**Note:**
Never having completed such appointment dialog I cannot be sure how it looks when finished

- the **reason** for the appointment is being asked for

  - first permit type and then if it is to be renewed

So selecting the **correct** permit type would therefore be a good idea

- so knowning the German term of what you need is crucial